# Multiple aggregates in SSRS 2005 matrix

Tags: reporting-services, matrix, reportingservices-2005

How can I get the aggregate information to appear in a matrix as in this example:

[image]

The query results are in a single row with columns representing each of the aggregate numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is something like this:

[image]

You can set up a **Matrix** object to display something similar to your requirements:

[image]

Here I dragged `City` and `Item` into the Matrix row and column field respectively, then added another Row Group based on `Category` and a Column Group based on `Date`.

The end result is practically the same as your requirement:

[image]

The big caveat here is that SSRS 2005 offers very limited options for customising a Matrix, i.e. things like adding new columns, but you can see the example report is pretty close so this is worth considering.

Comment: Ian, that is what I ended up doing. The original query had delv. sales, qoh, diff as column names. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Report Design:**

You can group by CITYID and instead of 1 detail line add 3 more detail and then put the corresponding field values.

With in the detail group right click the row and say add row within group and repeat it 3 times.

**Database:**

Other way is modify your dataset to break into four rows for each CITYID. Something Like

```
SELECT 'Delv' AS RowTag, Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM Table
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sales' AS RowTag, Field4, Field5, Field6  FROM Table
UNION ALL
SELECT 'QOH' AS RowTag, Field7, Field8, Field9  FROM Table
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Diff' AS RowTag, Field10, Field11, Field12  FROM Table
```

Comment: Anup, my original query had them each as a separate column. I changed my query logic similar to yours where I did several unions and that seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Glad my answer helped you. Currently you don't have enough points to upvote so thats fine.